# how to change two dates to number of days and hours jango

Tags: django, python-datetime

i'm trying to change two dates `check_in and check_out` to days and hours

my models.py

```
check_in = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
check_out = models.DateTimeField()
```

i tried this

```
check_in_date = obj.check_in
check_out_date = obj.check_out
days = check_out_date - check_in_date 
day = days.days
hour = days.seconds / 60
```

for the `day` it works as i expect except that when i select this two dates `check_in=05-07-2021 04:46 PM` to `check_out=05-07-2021 10:46 PM` i want to show `0 days 6 hours` but it show `0 days  360.0 hours` !
is it possible to return such date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need subtract `check_in_date` from `check_out_date`, furthemore you should divide the `seconds` by 3600, not 60. We can implement this with:

```
check_in_date = obj.check_in
check_out_date = obj.check_out
days = check_out_date - check_in_date
day = days.days
hour = days.seconds // 3600
```

Comment: can we get minutes as well ? for example `check_in=05-07-2021 04:00 PM` to `check_out=05-07-2021 10:30 PM` to return 6:30 min?

Comment: HunarMohammed: yes, with `(days.seconds // 60) % 60` as minute. You should also format this with a leading `0` if the values is less than 10.

Comment: i cant appreciate  you enough